# What are the different "Click Methods" available through the gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, configuration, gnome-tweak-tool

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I have recently noticed that there is a `Click Methods` pull-down menu in the `gnome-tweak-tool`'s `Keyboard and Mouse` section:

[image: Click Method]

Here are the options which it provides:

[image: Click Method Available Options]

But what are all these options? And what do they do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748850) is the bug report that got it added
- It points to this [document](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad_softbuttons.html) (The link has images to explain it). From the link:

> **Software button areas**
>
> On most clickpads, this is the default behavior. The bottom of the touchpad is split in the middle to generate left or right button events on click. The height of the button area depends on the hardware but is usually around 10mm.
>
> Left, right and middle button events can be triggered as follows:
>
> - if a finger is in the main area or the left button area, a click generates left button events.
> - if a finger is in the right area, a click generates right button events.
> - if there is a finger in both the left and right button area, a click generates middle button events.

= area = default for non-Apple

> **Clickfinger behavior**
>
> This is the default behavior on Apple touchpads. Here, a left, right, middle button event is generated when one, two, or three fingers are held down on the touchpad when a physical click is generated. The location of the fingers does not matter and there are no software-defined button areas.

= fingers = default for Apple

---

The other 2 have not got a definition on it. "default" will be what the hardware is expecting. So when you use a none-Apple it does "fingers" otherwise it does "area". "none" I would guess it disables clicking the touchpad.

Comment: What about the `Default` and `None` options?

Comment: I just tested the `None` option and it appears same as `Default`, or at least, there is no noticeable difference that I noticed...